# Clear console for every pages loaded (asynchrone api print)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

I have a reactJS app,
traditional structure,

App.tsx
index.tsx etc..

I use some private lib, and unfortunatly they print some data in the console that I dont want to show to our users.
(like some object structure, or some debug)

I'm looking for a simple way to clear the console everytimes a page is loaded so at least It will look "empty"

Problem is the API send some prints after so my console is clear, but I see print just after

Comment: `console.clear()`?

Answer (score 0):

use `console.clear()` after page loaded.

**EDIT:**

Whenever API data updates you can clear via `useEffect`.

```
  const [apiList, setApiList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApiData() // call api request...
    console.clear();
  }, [apiList]);
```

Comment: problem is I have post "API" return
So I see console cleared then the print in it I edited my initial post

Comment: ```useEffect``` will help you, I update my answer.